# transparent background on tooltip control

Tags: c, winapi, background, tooltip, transparent

I was able to do custom painting on the tooltip control, by disable its visual style.

I am curious that if we can make the tooltip control to be "Layered" (i.e transparent).

I tried to add WS_EX_LAYERED style on it and call

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwndTooltip, 0, 50, LWA_ALPHA);
```

But it doesn't become transparent.

I did this for the manin window and the main window become transparent.

After searching, there is no further information about how to make tooltip transparent.

So `How to make tooltip control transparent background?`

p.s: hwndTooltip is a child of Desktop, not of main window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be done.  Reference and explanation:

http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/wtl/message/14214